# How do I get this neat avatar + rep + badges image?

Tags: support, flair

The other day, I saw the blog of an SO member. In it, there was an image of his SO avatar and his reputation and badges. It looked *cool*. Is there any easy way for me to get something like that, tailored to me?

Comment: How about migrating this to meta?

Comment: Well the answer is on this site so I think it's allright.

Comment: Obviously, I posted that while it was in SO `:)`

Comment: By "this site" I mean stackoverflow.com. 
Hitting the link "flair tab" from Christopher will return you to SO. So I still think I'm right. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to the [flair page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165147/radbyx/flair) available from your profile to get the code.

Comment: Thanks alot, just what I was hoping to find. I even open an account on Meta and searched it also :) I'll accept in 8 minuts, when I able too.